# Is there a way to access the badgeValue of IOS for tabviews using nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to create badges for ios tabs,i know normally you can access it in swift using the badgeValue variable, is there a similar way to do so in nativescript

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may access the native attribute. You may also embed a Label in Android's TabView to mimic the iOS badge feature

```
const tabView = <any>args.object;
if (isIOS) {
    tabView.items.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.bageValue) {
            item.__controller.tabBarItem.badgeValue = item.bageValue;
        }
    });
}
if (isAndroid) {
    tabView._badges = {};
    const nativeTabView = tabView._tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    for (let i = 0; i < nativeTabView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        addBadges(tabView, i, nativeTabView.getChildAt(i), tabView.items[i].bageValue);
    }
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=i44ty0&v=3)

**Note:** The example is in TypeScript, with Vue just the framework syntax to add listeners / methods may vary.

Comment: Sorry this is late but this helped a lot thank you 